# What to do when your training Dataset fields for a classification model are not constant or change?

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to train an image classification model by first passing training images through Google vision API to extract image properties such as color and then creating a training data set with labels. The classification model will be trained to identify certain landscapes using color properties. The issue is some of the images that pass through Google vision API have 9 colors or 8 or 7. It is not constant. Will this be a problem or affect the effectiveness of the model? I cannot control how many colors are present in photos. Any advise or recommendations?

Comment: you can use the maximum number of colors that can be returned as number of inputs and simply use dummy values for colors that are not returned

Comment: thanks for the reply, the dummy values have to be the same? to avoid some sort of bias right?

Comment: You can use same values as long as the dummy values are distinct from color values